# Understanding why certain bit manipulation operations are performed

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, keytab

Below is the source code of Keytab implementation in Java. This snippet reads the key version from the keytab file. I am having trouble understanding how this works.
Why is the bitwise AND and shift left operation performed?

What my code calls:

```
KeyTab keytab = KeyTab.getInstance(keytabFile); // passing keytab file location.
```

This file is in binary format. KeyTabInputStream reads the data.

```java
  private void load(KeyTabInputStream var1) throws IOException, RealmException {
        this.entries.clear();
        **this.kt_vno = var1.readVersion();**
        if (this.kt_vno == 1281) {
            var1.setNativeByteOrder();
        }

        boolean var2 = false;

        while(var1.available() > 0) {
            int var4 = var1.readEntryLength();
            KeyTabEntry var3 = var1.readEntry(var4, this.kt_vno);
            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println(">>> KeyTab: load() entry length: " + var4 + "; type: " + (var3 != null ? var3.keyType : 0));
            }

            if (var3 != null) {
                this.entries.addElement(var3);
            }
        }

    }
```

```java
    public int readVersion() throws IOException {
        int var1 = (this.read() & 255) << 8;
        return var1 | this.read() & 255;
    }
```

Comment: Please add more context. Pointing to online source code or at least pasting whole method body so types and semantics are clear to people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.read()` presumably returns 8 "interesting" bits since `& 255` "retrieves" only the last 8 bits, shifting that by 8 bits means that now the bits 9-16 hold the data.
Then performing another read + `&` again gets 8 bits, `|` that with the shifted bits from the step prior you now have one `int` with 16 relevant bits set: bit 1-8 hold the result of the second read while bits 9-16 hold the bits of the first read.

Comment: more *probable* that `read` is returning a `byte` (also 8 bits, agreed) and you need `& 255` to *avoid* (counteract) sign expansion